# Way to write an iOS app on a Windows system?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, windows, macos

I come to you as a Windows user all my life, so my knowledge of iOS, Apple, and Macs are incredibly limited.

I'm trying to create an iOS app. I know that most iOS apps are now written in Swift (and used to be in Objective-C), which seem to "require" Xcode and/or SwiftUI (not 100% sure about this). Is there a way to write an iOS app in Windows or without using a Mac device? It's nothing too complicated, featuring a simple UI, text submission boxes, and links to other pages of the app.

I know I can use a Virtual Machine or other methods to interact with Mac/iOS software, but is there an easier way to do this? Can I simply code everything in a regular text editor and compile it elsewhere?

Additionally, can I write an iOS app in a different language besides Swift or Objective-C? OR can I use Swift, SwiftUI, and/or Xcode in Windows?

Basically - is there an easy way for me to write an iOS app in Windows? Any and all help would be deeply appreciated. Stay healthy out there.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio to write Xamarin apps in C#.  Ultimately though, whatever you use to write your app you will need access to a Mac to build an iOS release to run on a device or upload to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is your best option here apart from it writing native multiplatform apps using dart it can also write platform-specific code for both Android (Java) and IOS (swift)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use React Native to write an iOS app on a Windows system.

Also additionally - Yes. You can write an iOS app in a different language besides Swift or Objective-C. React Native will let you write an iOS app in Javascript.

Hope this helps someone!